# In tmux how should I bind a key in the 'emacs-edit' table?

Tags: tmux, key-binding

I find that when I am editing a command in tmux, the <kbd>M-b</kbd> and <kbd>M-f</kbd> are not bound. I tried the following:

```
tmux bind-key -t emacs-edit M-b previous-word
```

But tmux says that's a unknown command. What command should I use when binding such a key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tmux doesn't have previous/next word editing commands at the moment.